# Pandas: How to calculate average one value to after another (succeeding average)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, average

Imagine a dataset like below:

```
result  country          start      end
5       A              2/14/2022    2/21/2022
10      A              2/21/2022    2/28/2022
30      B              2/28/2022    3/7/2022
50      C               1/3/2022    1/10/2022
60      C              1/10/2022    1/17/2022
70      D              1/17/2022    1/24/2022
40      E              1/24/2022    1/31/2022
20      E              1/31/2022    2/7/2022
30      A              2/7/2022     2/14/2022
20      B              2/14/2022    2/21/2022
```

**Expected output**

I need to do groupby (country, start, and end) and the result column should add existing value with the above value and need to populate the average column.
For example:

groupby **country, start, and end** with result and average column is nothing but 5, 5+10/2, 10+30/2, 30+50/2,50+60/2

```
result   average 
5         5            eg: (5)     
10        7.5           (5+10/2)  #resultcol of existingvalue + abovevalue divided by 2 = average
30        20            (10+30/2)
50        40            (30+50/2)
60        55            (50+60/2)
70        65            ...
40        55            ...
20        30            ...
30        25            ...
20        25            ...
```

Comment: I've figured out your expected output is not grouping by country and date, appreciated if you could modify to let me verify with my solution

Comment: I want to do groupby country and date with the above mentioned logic. @PPP

Comment: I got it, but your expected output is not the result grouped by country and date, you are performing the calculation for the whole dataset in column 'average'

Comment: yes, you are right! @PPP

Comment: Therefore, my answer could help you if your dataset is large enough, i.e. there are at least 2 rows in a subset grouped by country and date

Comment: yes I have large dataset, I have provided the sample df. Please check the updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242371/discussion-between-ppp-and-mahilan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution with **grouping by country and date**, however it may raise error if there is no sufficient data in a subset (i.e. larger than 2):

```
df_data['average'] = df_data.groupby(['country', 'date'])['result'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

In case you want to **group by country only**

```
df_data['average'] = df_data.groupby(['country'])['result'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(0, drop=True)

df_data
  country       date  result  average
0       A  2/14/2022       5      5.0
1       A  2/21/2022      10      7.5
2       B  2/28/2022      30     30.0
3       C   1/3/2022      50     50.0
4       C  1/10/2022      60     55.0
5       D  1/17/2022      70     70.0
6       E  1/24/2022      40     40.0
7       E  1/31/2022      20     30.0
8       A   2/7/2022      30     20.0
9       B  2/14/2022      20     25.0
```

Comment: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index I'm getting this error while doing groupby by country and date @Dharman. Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: @Mahilan If your dataset is grouped by country and date, there will be only one row in subset since your dataset is not large enough to perform such operation